# Get rows when trying to access columns in a python script

Tags: python, rows, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns

I'm having a problem that seems like the answer would be easily explained. 
I'm improting from a csv file with rows and columns using the code:

```
import csv
import os
import glob
import numpy as np

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)                      
        return list(reader)

all_data = []

path=raw_input('What is the directory?')       
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
     all_data.extend(get_data(infile))
a = np.array(all_data)
col=a[:,[0,1]]
print col
```

However the result produces the first two rows rather than columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably your data. Verify that the CSV data is read correctly (debug the reader).

When I run your script with the following input files:

file1.csv

```
foo,bar,baz
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

file2.csv

```
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,8
```

Then the result of your script is the following:

```
$ python test.py
[['4' '5']
 ['5' '6']
 ['6' '7']
 ['foo' 'bar']
 ['1' '2']
 ['2' '3']
 ['3' '4']]
```

Therefore I think your bug must be about reading the CSV files. Maybe the column separator isn't working correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot, now running one file at a time and seems to work